How can I create a grid line animation for my homepage similar to Acertinity UI using pure HTML, CSS, and JavaScript?
I am trying to replicate the grid line animation effect seen on the Acertinity UI homepage using pure HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. Below is a GIF of the animation effect I am referring to:
Click to See Image Of the Animation
I have basic knowledge of HTML, CSS, and JavaScript but I'm not sure how to implement this particular effect. Can someone guide me on how to achieve this?
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Grid Line Animation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid-container">
        <!-- Content goes here -->
    </div>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

CSS (styles.css):
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #000;
}

.grid-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.grid-line {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

.horizontal-line {
    height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
}

.vertical-line {
    width: 1px;
    height: 100%;
}

JavaScript (scripts.js):
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const gridContainer = document.querySelector('.grid-container');

    // Add horizontal lines
    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        const line = document.createElement('div');
        line.classList.add('grid-line', 'horizontal-line');
        line.style.top = `${i * 5}%`;
        gridContainer.appendChild(line);
    }

    // Add vertical lines
    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        const line = document.createElement('div');
        line.classList.add('grid-line', 'vertical-line');
        line.style.left = `${i * 5}%`;
        gridContainer.appendChild(line);
    }

    // Add animation logic here
});

I’m not sure how to add the animation to these lines to make them move or pulse like in the GIF. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

You can animate the grid lines you designed by adding CSS animations to achieve the effect of a grid line animation such as the one on the Acertinity UI homepage. This would mean that lines may be animated for opacity and probably position of these lines, which can pulsate or traverse different paths.
.grid-line {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    /* Added animation property to apply the pulse effect */
    animation: pulse 2s infinite;
}

/* Keyframes for the pulse animation */
@keyframes pulse {
    0%, 100% {
        opacity: 0.1; /* Starting and ending opacity */
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0.5; /* Midway opacity */
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const gridContainer = document.querySelector('.grid-container');

    // Add horizontal lines
    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        const line = document.createElement('div');
        line.classList.add('grid-line', 'horizontal-line');
        line.style.top = `${i * 5}%`; // Position each line at 5% intervals
        gridContainer.appendChild(line);
    }

    // Add vertical lines
    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        const line = document.createElement('div');
        line.classList.add('grid-line', 'vertical-line');
        line.style.left = `${i * 5}%`; // Position each line at 5% intervals
        gridContainer.appendChild(line);
    }
});

